# Async css with integrity

Tags: html, css, asynchronous

Css preload without integrity works and rel=stylesheet with integrity works too. But what I want to do is to make async css with integrity. Am I miss something?

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY"></noscript>
```

My browser can't load css with this code. Empty dev console. This intended to be easy, why this happens?

Comment: Why not just put the CSS before `</body>`? In fact, I thought CSS could be fetched in parallel.

Comment: Already before </body>. Google pagespeed test recommends async load for css.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, here is a proof:
I have a bootstrap styled button that will get its styling after 1.5 seconds from finishing the preload.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">i will become bootstrappified after 1.5seconds!</button>

<script>
  function updateRel(cssPreload) {
    if (cssPreload.rel !== 'stylesheet') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('will take effect now!');
        cssPreload.rel = 'stylesheet';
      }, 1500);
    }
  }
</script>

<link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY" as="style"
onload="updateRel(this)">
```